# Right Click and left click options needs comes near to the clicking row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

For the product, the mouse click options are wrote for action gear icon only. So if we left click on Task button(action icon), it will show options near to that icon.

[image: While left click on the icon it showing options]

and corresponding inspect(F12) html file is here:

```
<tr id="ember25477" class="ember-view content-row body-row-view container-view" tabindex="0" aria-label="">
<td id="ember25657" class="ember-view content-data item-number item-number-view container-view item-number-view-core_component_data-view-mixin container-view-core_component_data-view-mixin itemNumber">
<div id="ember25660" class="ember-view view">
<div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td id="ember25666" class="ember-view container-view">
<rs-icon id="ember25669" class="ember-view action-menu auto-actions-menu-button icon clickable-icon" style="width: 1em; height: 1em; font-size: 20px">
<icon glyph="action" class="action" style="font-size: 20px;">
</icon>
</rs-icon>
<span id="ember25672" class="ember-view view">
</span>
</td>
<td id="ember25678" class="ember-view content-data view view-core_component_data-view-mixin description">
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="aria-hidden">Empty cell</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

But Now the new requirement is options have have to wherever click (both on right click and left click) on that corresponding row. So I have tried the below code:

```
click: function (event) {
            var eventResult = this.get('tableView').clickRow(event, this.get('object'));
            if (eventResult !== false) {
                this.get('element').focus();
                $('.content-row').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var rowParentId = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
                    $('#'+rowParentId).find( ".action-menu" ).click();
                });
            }
            return eventResult;
        },
```

When I'm using the above code, right click option is working fine at the corresponding row. But the options are coming near to the gear icon only.  I need the options needs to come near to wherever I click on that row.

Please provide me any other suggestion for this. Your help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically you just need your "context menu" to offset to where your mouse is.  To get the coordinates of your mouse use "event.pageX" and "event.pageY".  Use that and move your context menu to that coordinate by using `$('context-menu-component').css({ top: event.pageY + 'px', left: event.pageX + 'px' })`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here but I will attempt an answer based on what I understand. This example will likely be a more "Ember Way" of doing it instead of breaking out to jQuery so please let me know if you can get it working and if not I will update my answer.

First of all, I would recommend that you use Ember's internal implementations of event binding, there are some [strange specifics](https://youtu.be/G9hXjjHFJVs) about interactions of dom events and Ember events so you should be very careful here. You can see a [full list](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/#toc_event-names) of events that can be handled automatically by a component in the Ember Guides.

The first thing that we do is we create a component for a table row so that each row is able to handle its own actions. We then use that component in the *main* template (either your route's template or a table component):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
      {{table-row item=item}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the component javascript file `table-row.js` you have the following code:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',

  showContextForEvent(event) {
    this.set('showContextMenu', true);
    this.set('x', event.clientX);
    this.set('y', event.clientY);
  },

  contextMenu(event) {
    this.showContextForEvent(event);

    return false;
  },
});
```

The key part of this is the `contextMenu(event)` call, this will be called with a dom event that you can use for whatever you need it to do. The `showContextMenu` boolean and the x and y are unlikely to be used in your setup and were just things that we did to get this working for the demo we were building in the video linked below.

---

We have recently uploaded a video of us answering your question (or one very similar to it) here https://youtu.be/mG8NbMh7_Ck. You can also see a full code snippet here https://github.com/stonecircle/ember-rightclick-example